# Hiding a drive in Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-registry

My computer (Windows 10 Home) has two GPT partitioned hard drives; an unencrypted C drive, and an encrypted Z drive that is mounted as an E drive via [Veracrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/).

[image]

Using [this tutorial](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/show-hide-a-drive-in-windows) I tried to hide the Z drive in Explorer by creating a DWord registry key at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer` set to `33554432` (decimal).

[image]

This was partially successful in that selecting the Z drive now produces an error (Location Not Available: The parameter is incorrect)

[image]

instead of asking me if I want to format the drive, however the Z drive is still visible.

Have I done something wrong in editing the registry, or are these Windows 7/8 instructions only partially applicable to Windows 10, or third option?

Comment: Why not just remove the drive letter from that partition via the Disk Manager?

Comment: If I do that then Veracrypt isn't able to find the drive to mount it

Comment: Would you be alright with relettering Z to D? Group Policy might be able to help then.

Comment: I'd be fine with that, but I think that Group Policy may not be enabled for Windows 10 Home - if I run "gpedit.msc" I get a "not found" error

Comment: Just to make sure, you rebooted after applying that registry change?

Comment: Yup (plus ten more characters)

Answer (score 0):

You can have VeraCrypt reference by partition name (something like \Device\HardDisk0\Partition4)

For removing the drive letter in windows explorer, you can use Windows built-in DiskPart utility:

1. Open elevated command prompt or powershell
2. Type: `diskpart`
3. Type: `list volume`
4. Identify the volume containing the drive letter you wish to hide e.g. 'Volume 4' will be used in remaining example that is assigned to drive E
5. Type: `select volume 4`
6. Verify message: *Volume 4 is the selected volume*
7. Type: `remove letter e`
8. Verify message: *DiskPart successfully removed the drive letter or mount point.*
9. Type: `exit`
10. Verify in File Explorer that the drive letter is no longer visible